# How to run part of the test cases using gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

In gtest main, when using

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Running tests\n");
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

It always run all the tests.

Is there a way to run some specific tests?

Comment: I don't even bother to write the main(), just link test cases to gtest_main.a XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to write a `main()` for gtest. You can just link with `gtest_main` library as well as `gtest` library. It is pretty similar to what you have, though.

Second, to run a specific test, please refer to [advanced options](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Running_Test_Programs%3A_Advanced_Options).

Comment: Or, simply speaking, `--gtest_filter=something`